# Comparing a Null to another value in MySQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, null, compare

So here is my issue I am comparing new and old values when a table row is being updated. But the new or old value will sometimes be null. So the code below doesn't work. Can can I remedy this issue?

Thank You

```
BEFORE UPDATE ON mytable
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
        IF OLD.assignedto != NEW.assignedto
        THEN
                INSERT INTO history
                    (
                        asset    ,
                        changedfield     ,
                        oldvalue    ,
                        newvalue      
                    )
                    VALUES
                    (
                        NEW.asset,
                        'assignedto',
                        OLD.assignedto,
                        NEW.assignedto
                    );
        END IF;
    END$$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
IF (   (OLD.assignedto IS NOT NULL AND NEW.assignedto IS NOT NULL 
             AND OLD.assignedto != NEW.assignedto)
    OR (OLD.assignedto IS NULL AND NEW.assignedto IS NOT NULL)
    OR (OLD.assignedto IS NOT NULL AND NEW.assignedto IS NULL)
   )
```

The comment is very much correct.

Comment: `NULL or <foo> or <bar>` will be `NULL`. You have to work with `COALESCE()`.

Comment: Your comment is correct except that you don't **absolutely have to** work with `COALESCE()`. That said, the coalescing answers are good.

Comment: thanks for the quick replies. This ended up working for me. I will know to do this in the future now.

Comment: @dan You really should look into `COALESCE` though -- don't ignore the other answers!

Comment: ya ill take a look at it. Your solution made the most sense to me right off hand.

Answer (score 21):

MySql has a special null-safe equality check operator:

> <=>
>
> NULL-safe equal. This operator performs an equality comparison like the = operator, but returns 1 rather than NULL if both operands
> are NULL, and 0 rather than NULL if one operand is NULL.

```
mysql> SELECT 1 <=> 1, NULL <=> NULL, 1 <=> NULL;
        -> 1, 1, 0
mysql> SELECT 1 = 1, NULL = NULL, 1 = NULL;
        -> 1, NULL, NULL
```

You can use this operator with the NOT operator:

```
mysql> SELECT NOT (1 <=> 1), NOT (NULL <=> NULL), NOT (1 <=> NULL);
        -> 0, 0, 1
```

So, in your case you should write:

```
IF NOT (OLD.assignedto <=> NEW.assignedto)
```

Comment: Most usefull answer for this question! +1

Answer (score 1):

nulls have to be compared with the `is null`/`is not null` construct:

```
if ((old.assignedto != new.assignedto) or (old.assignedto is null) or (new.assignedto is null))
```

You'l have to adjust that to match your requirements as this will come back true if either is null or they're not equal to each other. Perhaps you need to handle the case where both are null.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare against NULL because NULL is defined as a value that never matches in a comparison, even other NULLS.  Try for yourself if you don't believe me.

```
SELECT NULL = NULL;
```

You will have to check that the column in question isn't null with IS NOT NULL.  You can use the AND or OR operator to incorporate such a test into the logic you already have.

Answer (score 1):

```
IF COALESCE(OLD.assignedto != NEW.assignedto, OLD.assignedto IS NULL AND NEW.assignedto IS NULL)
```

If the `OLD.assignedto != NEW.assignedto` part has one operator `NULL`, the whole expression gets `NULL`, making `COALESCE()` return the next argument instead which returns the truth value to use when one of them is `NULL` - the other one must be `NULL`as well.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but there's a slightly clearer way to write that condition:

```
IF COALESCE(OLD.assignedto, 0) <> COALESCE(NEW.assignedto, 0) THEN ...
```

This way you tell the engine to replace NULLs with a 0 so the condition won't fail by comparing to NULL.