# Update Trigger.. Not Working as intended?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am learning how to construct Triggers in MYSQL, I have constructed a Trigger that will recalculate the Department Salary if one of the Department Employees is updated (either their salary is updated or they are added to/removed from the department). If I update a user's salary, it is not updating the departments salary as well.

Employee Table:

```
SSN
Salary
Name
Dno
Supervisor_ssn
```

Department Table:

```
DName
Dno
Total_sal
Manager_SSN
```

Trigger looks as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `Employee_AUPD` AFTER UPDATE ON `Employee` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF old.salary != new.salary THEN
    UPDATE department SET total_sal = total_sal - old.salary
        WHERE new.dno = department.dno;
    UPDATE department SET total_sal = total_sal + new.salary
        WHERE new.dno = department.dno;
 END IF;
 IF old.dno != new.dno THEN
    UPDATE department SET total_sal = total_sal - old.salary
        WHERE old.dno = department.dno;
    UPDATE department SET total_sal = total_sal + new.salary
        WHERE new.dno = department.dno;
 END IF;
END;
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: works for me here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1426e/3

Comment: The record I was updating had NULL values for Salary and Dno, I am wondering if that had something to do with it. Like you said, it works great for records that do not have NULL values.

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999295/comparing-a-null-to-another-value-in-mysql-trigger (you should have included the problem was with null values in the question).

Answer (score 0):

You have a logic error. If the salary *and* the department changes, the first IF block substracts the old salary from the new department.

But you don't need to test anything. Simply code these two update statements:

```
UPDATE department SET
total_sal = total_sal - old.salary
WHERE department.dno = old.dno;

UPDATE department SET
total_sal = total_sal + new.salary
WHERE department.dno = new.dno;
```

This logic is steaightforward and can't fail.