# Mysql BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGER set certain column value before the actual update on the same column

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to set `STATUS` column value to null before an update happen in `TABLE_A` regardless whether the update changes the `STATUS` column value or not. Suppose that the update statement looks like this
`UPDATE TABLE_A SET STATUS=0, STATUS_A=1;`,
i want to change the `STATUS` column value to null first before it is set to 0. Or if the update statement looks like this `UPDATE TABLE_A SET STATUS_A=1;`, i want to change the `STATUS` column value to null first. I created a trigger before update code like below

```
delimiter $$
 CREATE TRIGGER DECISION_CHANGES BEFORE UPDATE ON TABLE_A
     FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
     IF NEW.STATUS_A<>OLD.STATUS_A THEN
     SET `STATUS` = NULL;
     ELSEIF NEW.STATUS_T1<>OLD.STATUS_T1 AND NEW.STATUS_TL1<>OLD.STATUS_TL1 THEN
     SET `STATUS` = NULL;
     ELSEIF NEW.STATUS_T2<>OLD.STATUS_T2 AND NEW.STATUS_TL2<>OLD.STATUS_TL2 THEN
     SET `STATUS` = NULL;
     END IF;
END$$
delimiter ;
```

But those code give me error probably because i can only set `new.STATUS` not `STATUS`. But if i did that, it will be like overwriting the actual update values won't it?(In the end it would write null, not 0)

How do i do that with trigger?if i can't do that with trigger, is there any workaround?
Thank you.

**UPDATE 1.**
I dont really understand how exactly the data flow works on trigger with before update clause but i tried to code it like below. Will it does things as i expect it will?

```
    delimiter $$
    CREATE TRIGGER DECISION_CHANGES BEFORE UPDATE ON TABLE_A
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    DECLARE tempSTATUS INT;
            DECLARE FLAG INT;
    IF OLD.`STATUS`<>NEW.`STATUS` THEN
       SET tempSTATUS=NEW.`STATUS`;
       SET FLAG=1;
    ELSEIF NEW.STATUS_T1<>OLD.STATUS_T1 AND NEW.STATUS_TL1<>OLD.STATUS_TL1 THEN
       SET tempSTATUS=NEW.`STATUS`;
       SET FLAG=1;
    ELSEIF NEW.STATUS_T2<>OLD.STATUS_T2 AND NEW.STATUS_TL2<>OLD.STATUS_TL2 THEN
       SET tempSTATUS=NEW.`STATUS`;
       SET FLAG=1;
       END IF;
    IF NEW.STATUS_A<>OLD.STATUS_A THEN
       SET `STATUS` = NULL;
    ELSEIF NEW.STATUS_T1<>OLD.STATUS_T1 AND NEW.STATUS_TL1<>OLD.STATUS_TL1 THEN
       SET `STATUS` = NULL;
    ELSEIF NEW.STATUS_T2<>OLD.STATUS_T2 AND NEW.STATUS_TL2<>OLD.STATUS_TL2 THEN
       SET `STATUS` = NULL;
    END IF;
    IF FLAG=1 THEN
       SET NEW.`STATUS`=tempSTATUS;
    END IF;
    END$$
        delimiter ;
```

Comment: It might help if you tell us *why* you want to do this. In any case, note that ["A<>B" isn't "true" if A or B is "null"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6999295).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Suppose that the update statement looks like this `UPDATE TABLE_A SET STATUS=0, STATUS_A=1`;, i want to change the STATUS column value to null first before it is set to 0.
>
> Or if the update statement looks like this `UPDATE TABLE_A SET STATUS_A=1;`, i want to change the STATUS column value to null first.
>
> I dont really understand how exactly the data flow works on trigger with before update clause

The term/word "first" is not correct.

When you execute UPDATE then, for each row which must be updated:

- The server creates temporary row which is a copy of current row state
- SET clause expressions of UPDATE are applied, some columns values in temporary row are changed, and new row state is formed
- BEFORE trigger additionally edits the values in this row state, for the columns which were both set or skipped in SET clause
- The row with the data state which is obtained after SET and trigger expressions is saved instead of old data into the table

I.e. you must simply set `NEW.column` to needed value. `NULL` in your case.

PS. In multiple-table UPDATE the server creates temporary row for each current row, in each table. If the row of some table must be updated a lot of time (together with different rows from other tables) then only one indefinite (by fact - the most first) row state is saved, and all another states are ignored. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/D5V3vLyK).

PPS. If more than one BEFORE trigger exists then they are applied one-by-one.

Answer (score 1):

> But those code give me error probably because i can only set
> new.STATUS not STATUS. But if i did that, it will be like overwriting
> the actual update values won't it?(In the end it would write null, not
> 0)

Yes, but you can work around that. If the value of `STATUS` is changed in the update, the result you want in that field is the new value. So it does not matter it it was set to NULL in-between or not.

You may perform your trigger to set its value to NULL only when it **not** changed by the update, like this.

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `DECISION_CHANGES` BEFORE UPDATE ON `TABLE_A` FOR EACH ROW
IF NEW.`STATUS` = OLD.`STATUS` THEN SET NEW.`STATUS` = NULL;
END IF
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Example with initial values like this :

| STATUS | STATUS_A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |

The following query :

```sql
UPDATE `TABLE_A`
SET `STATUS` = '3', `STATUS_A` = '4'
WHERE `STATUS` = '1' AND `STATUS_A` = '2'
```

Results in :

| STATUS | STATUS_A |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 4 |

While the following query :

```sql
UPDATE `TABLE_A`
SET `STATUS_A` = '4'
WHERE `STATUS` = '1' AND `STATUS_A` = '2'
```

Results in :

| STATUS | STATUS_A |
| --- | --- |
| NULL | 4 |